# Firebase Permission denied crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have implemented firebase .
 but when child dont have permission app is crashing i am getting

```
Fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.database.d
 Firebase Database error: Permission denied
  Listener.onCancelled
```

and my inCancelled look like

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    try {
        Observable.onError(databaseError.toException());
    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but still it crash . how i can prevent this crash

i am saying if some one  change child permission is any way we
can stop this crash

Comment: can you provide more detailed exception log?

Comment: Check the permissions you've set inside Firebase Console.

Comment: @koceeng
Fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.database.d
Firebase Database error: Permission denied
 Raw Text
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException (Unknown Source)

Comment: @SrikarReddy i am saying if we have given wrong permission how we can stop crash

Comment: in your `google-services.json` and in firebase console, did your app package name (like `com.example.what`) is same as your project package name?

Comment: You're trying to read data that you don't have access to. That's the only reason this exception will be raised. If it is unclear what would cause that, share the [minimal code, JSON and security rules (all as plain text please, no screenshots) that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so der is no way i can stop this crash even i dont have permssion ? coz say in real time some one del this permssion or change then how we can prevent this crash

Comment: Database authorization can only be changed by app administrators. It is not possible for users of your app to change the access permissions. So these errors are very closely under your control. To stop raising an exception, simply handle `onCancelled` differently.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like problem with your **google-services.json.**

Make sure **app name** and **client id** are **same** as in firebase console.

If you are not sure re-download google-services.json from your project's console and add it your project.

Comment: i am getting reponse but y question is any way we can handle

Comment: what if i removed and app is live , is any way i can prevent crash

Comment: maybe youllget crash or no response

Comment: i am getting crash any catch ?

Comment: the rules are important tho

Comment: can you tell me what is your requirement so that i can come up with solution

Comment: my requirement is how  we can stop crash if in run time some one remove this permission from dashboard

Comment: as per my knowledge there is no way you can do it without making new build

Answer (score 0):

If you attach a listener to a location where the user doesn't have read permission, the Firebase client will call `onCancelled` on that listener. Your current code raises that as an exception.

If you don't want to raise an exception, just handle `onCancelled` differently:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Toast.makeText(
        getApplicationContext(), 
        "You don't have permission to read this data", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

An important thing to realize is that `onCancelled` being called is almost always a mistake in the code. It is not something the user of your app does wrong, but the code attaching a listener to the wrong location. So just displaying the error to the user is probably not the best idea.

For brevity you'll often see me raising the exception in sample snippets. But since this is a mistake in my code, in actual apps Id like this error to show up in Crash Reporting:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    FirebaseCrash.report(databaseError.toException());
}
```

Comment: This did not help. There are still occasional crashes even though onCancelled is implemented.